# What is the right tool to process big .xel files (SQL Server Extended Events logs)?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, extended-events

My aim is to audit all queries on an instance, who's running them and from where, how many reads, in order to consolidate/migrate on another instance.

Figured out the best way is via Extended Events to .xel files, over 2 weeks, copy those and analyse on my well-specd desktop. Set up the capture with the minimal number of details (fields), so really can't make it smaller than this - aprox 12GB in 12 files. Used "Merge Extended Event Files" in SSMS to load the .xel files and process as detailed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/advanced-viewing-of-target-data-from-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Is this really the best way to do it ? Is there a better tool to load the files ? It's really **slow** with SSMS 17.7 - example: with only 4 filters so far (before getting into grouping and aggregates) it took over 12h to get to crunch through 50% of the logs.

Comment: Have you tried doing this with TSQL : sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file loading it to a table and doing filtering there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For large XE trace files, I use custom tooling with [QueryableXEventData](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/extended_events/2011/07/20/introducing-the-extended-events-reader/). I've found this to be much faster than XML parsing in T-SQL.

Below is a basic PowerShell that imports selected fields and actions from an `rpc_completed` event trace into a table in 10K batches. You'll need to include an `Add-Type` command for the `Microsoft.SqlServer.XE.Core.dll` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll` assemblies, which will be in your SQL Server installation folder with the exact location will varying depending on SQL version and chosen install location.

```
$SharedPath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared";
$SqlInstanceName = "";

$xeCore = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($SharedPath, "Microsoft.SqlServer.XE.Core.dll");
$xeLinq = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($SharedPath, "Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll");
Add-Type -Path $xeLinq;

if( [System.IO.File]::Exists($xeCore) )
{
    Add-Type -Path $xeCore;
}
```

Note that there are separate Fields and Actions collections in the [`PublishedEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.xevent.linq.publishedevent.aspx) class so you'll need to extract values from the appropriate connection.

```
# create target table
$connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString)
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(@"
CREATE TABLE dbo.rpc_completed(
      event_name sysname
    , timestamp datetimeoffset
    , statement nvarchar(MAX)
    , username nvarchar(256)
);
"@, $connection)
$connection.Open()
[void]$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
$connection.Close()

# data table for SqlBulkCopy
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("event_name", [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
$dt.Columns["event_name"].MaxLength = 256
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("timestamp", [System.Type]::GetType("System.DateTimeOffset"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("statement", [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("username", [System.Type]::GetType("System.String"))
$dt.Columns["username"].MaxLength = 128
$dt.Columns["statement"].MaxLength = -1

$events = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.QueryableXEventData("D:\TraceFiles\Log\rpc_completed*.xel")

# import XE events from file(s)
$bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionString)
$bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.rpc_completed"
$eventCount = 0
foreach($event in $events) {
    $eventCount += 1
    $row = $dt.NewRow()
    $dt.Rows.Add($row)
    $row["event_name"] = $event.Name
    $row["timestamp"] = $event.Timestamp
    $row["statement"] = $event.Fields["statement"].Value
    # username is a collected action
    $row["username"] = $event.Actions["username"].Value
    if($eventCount % 10000 -eq 0) {
        $bcp.WriteToServer($dt)
        $dt.Rows.Clear()
    }
}
$bcp.WriteToServer($dt) # write last batch
Write-Host "$eventCount records imported"
```

Comment: Thank you, the import seems fast enough. How would you add more fields to this, say username, database_name and client_app_name ? I've tried to add based on the existing logic, but end up with NULL in these new columns.

Comment: @RazvanZoitanu, I updated my answer with how to extract action data.

Comment: Thanks again, accepted the answer as I was able to import all I need, and fast! Looks like SSMS can only use 2GB of memory, and that's why it's so slow.. Last questions, getting this exception, any ideas on how to fix it ? Seems like all the data is in there, did max length on "statement" shows 235k chars.

Comment: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
At line:15 char:5
+     $row["statement"] = $event.Fields["statement"].Value
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Xml.XmlException

Comment: @RazvanZoitanu, lets continue the discussion in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77686/discussion-related-to-https-dba-stackexchange-com-questions-206863-what-is-the).

Comment: So it seems there is a bug in `QueryableXEventData` with regards to accessing the collect `statement` action of the `module_end` event. The workaround is to either not collecting the statement  with the `module_end` event or skip the statement column when importing that event. In this case, there were other detail events in the trace so the module_end statement was redundant.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to read and parse XEvents currently is by using the new XELite library from Microsoft. You can find it here: [XELite in NuGet.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.XELite/)
If you are PowerShell guy you can use the updated SQLServer module which is based on the XELite library. You can find it in the gallery: [SQLServer](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer).

Comment: Where can i find the documentation regarding `XELite`. ?